# Consequences of contributing too much to your Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, excess-contribution

What happens if you contribute to your Roth IRA at the beginning of the year, but then find out that you're over the allowable income to be able to contribute?  You might not always know at the beginning of the year how much you're going to make and you don't want to miss out on a whole year of growth just to wait and see.

Does the IRS make you withdraw the money or can you keep it in there, but pay some kind of tax?